# userAgent result different from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, user-agent

my site uses browser detection on login, on login this detection is achieved using JavaScript and the verification script in PHP it works pretty good but on IE trouble begins, as the JavaScript navigator.userAgent returns

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko

And PHP only returns

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

What's the fix for this? If there is some. I could not find anything about this even on MS website. On Opera, FireFox and Chrome the scripts are working just fine...

Comment: "on IE trouble begins"....should be "on IE trouble continues"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sniffing browser, perhaps use the `get_browser()` function... but you should not rely on user agents!

It's up to the browser to determine what to set as its user agent for HTTP_USER_AGENT.

Lastly, Starting with IE11, the user-agent string no longer includes the version token.

Comment: so, what do you recomend to use instead of userAgent? What I search for is something unique on each PC, on desktop apps I use motherboard SN and MAC Address to create the hash. And I wanted smoething like it for this but ended up using userAgent although not being unique it served my purpose. Any hints for a reliable alternative

Comment: I'm assuming you're wanting something unique per anonymous user, based on some sort of criteria. Check this out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/is-browser-fingerprinting-a-viable-technique-for-identifying-anonymous-users